# Add uploaded file image to json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Im trying to add the image that i upload in the json file but the problem is the image path always return to null when viewing in json file. Kindly Help. Thank you. Here is the code.It is already append successfully but the probelem is the image is always returning to null. I want to display the image to my json file and not returning to null anymore.

PHP

```
<?php  
 $message = '';  
 $error = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["name"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Name</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["gender"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Gender</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["designation"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Designation</label>";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           if(file_exists('employee_data.json'))  
           {  
                $current_data = file_get_contents('employee_data.json');  
                $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
                $extra = array(  
                     'name'               =>     $_POST['name'],  
                     'gender'          =>     $_POST["gender"],  
                     'designation'     =>     $_POST["designation"] ,
                     'image'       => $_POST["output"]

                );  
                $array_data['data'][] = $extra;  
                $final_data = json_encode($array_data);  

                if(file_put_contents('employee_data.json', $final_data))  
                {  
                     $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";  
                }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $error = 'JSON File not exits';  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="">Append Data to JSON File</h3><br />                 
                <form method="post">  
                     <?php   
                     if(isset($error))  
                     {  
                          echo $error;  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" /><br />  
                     <label>Gender</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" /><br />  
                     <label>Designation</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="designation" class="form-control" /><br />  
                      <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
                     <hr>

                    <h2>Output</h2>        
                    <div class="output" name="output">
                        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea><br>
                        <a name="new"></a><br><br>
                        <img><br>
                    </div>
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Append" class="btn btn-info" /><br />                      
                     <?php  
                     if(isset($message))  
                     {  
                          echo $message;  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                </form>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>  

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function encodeImageFileAsURL(cb) {
    return function(){
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            cb(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

$('#inputFileToLoad').change(encodeImageFileAsURL(function(base64Img){
    $('.output')
      .find('textarea')
        .val(base64Img)
        .end()
      .find('a')
        .attr('href', base64Img)
        .text(base64Img)
        .end()
      .find('img')
        .attr('src', base64Img);
}));
 </script>
```

employee_data.json

```
{"data":[{"name":"sdfghj","gender":"as","designation":"asdfg","image":null}]}
```

[image: Photo that i want to save in json file]

Comment: Have you tried to `echo` the base64 string for the image after submitting to the server? `$_POST["output"]` It would be a good idea to ensure you are sending/receiving the expected data in the POST before trying to work with it on the server...

Comment: yes i did but it give me error

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? The more information you can provide about any errors or unexpected behaviour the easier it might be to help you. **Also** if you can explain what steps and expectations are that would be helpful. When I run the source code you have provided it causes the page to crash.

Comment: yeah your right thank you the error is "Undefined index: output in C:\wamp64\www\json\new.php on line 29
"

Comment: i did upload a photo

Comment: While it's possible to upload a file through JSON, it's not a great idea. Using FormData is a much better solution for sending binary data

Comment: how to do that? im really sorry

Comment: @Wonderer Also you are using `jQuery` to handle the `change` events for the `file` input but you also use the `onchange` attribute on the `input` element for `files`

Comment: @Wonderer I have also come to notice `<div class="output" name="output">` is incorrect. You need to remove the `name` attribute from that `div` and add it to the `textarea` within that element `<textarea class="form-control" name="output"></textarea>`